# Very strange Parse.com app Error 100

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, parse-platform

I have a **very** strange problem with my Parse.com app.
First of all, here's the link: [linksync.parseapp.com](http://linksync.parseapp.com) (I provide it here so you can view source code) 
Everything was fine until now.. 
Recently I was unable to log in with my account from my Android phone. As I'm the owner of site, I changed my pass in Parse.com data browser and tried again. No luck! I tried logging via PC Browser - ok. 
**That's what I have for now:**
When I log in from Android Browser - Login failed
When I try to register new account to my website from Android Browser - `Error: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: {}` 
When I try to log in from my Android app for this website - Login fail
**BUT!** 
When I log in from **another** Android phone (either from Android browsers or my app) or from **any PC**, it works! 
Looks like my phone is cursed :( I even tried reflashing ROM and updated in to different version, but still can't make this work.
Oh, and from my phone another app, that uses parse.com, doesn't work. It's just as if I'm banned with the only device.

 Guys, what can I do to fix it? Any Parse.com devs here?

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, didn't have a clue what caused the error.

Well, you know what?

It turned out that I had no network connection on my phone!
After turning on WIFI on y phone it just worked fine, of course.

Takeaway: it's probably a good idea to build a network connectivity check into your app. When it starts up and there is no connectivity you give a warning to the user and quit (or continue to run in 'offline' mode).